# How to set the colored boxes in a specific order in plotly box plot?

Tags: python, plotly, boxplot

I currently have a boxplot in plotly like so:
[image]

Below is the Code I used to generate it:

```
data = Audit_grouped[(Audit_grouped['type'] == t)
                      & (Audit_grouped['rank_desc'] == i)]
              

fig = px.box(data, x = "year", y = "hours", color = "results",
             color_discrete_map = {'Pass': 'green', 'Fail': 'red'},
             labels={"hours":"hours(sum)"}
             )

fig.update_layout(xaxis={'categoryorder':'category ascending'})
fig.update_traces(quartilemethod="linear")
fig.show()
fig.write_image('Audit '+ str(i) + ' (' + str(t) + ').png')
```

I want to have the Fail boxplot be displayed on the left side first as opposed to it being on the right side.

How would I go on to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define that with the parameter `category_orders` when you create the box plot instead of updating the axes

in your case this will be as follow:

```py
fig = px.box(data, x = "year", y = "hours", color = "results",
             color_discrete_map = {'Pass': 'green', 'Fail': 'red'},
             labels={"hours":"hours(sum)"},
             category_orders={"results": ["Fail", "Pass"]}) # this is new line
```